# Python implementation of theta model (theta method)

Tags: python, r, time-series, forecasting

The theta model from this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207000000662) which achieved excellent results in the M3 compition is implemented in R: `thetaf` ([source](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/theta.R)).
I was looking for an implementation in python. Is there any implementation of it in python i.e. in sklearn or any other library?

Comment: Hey, i know it's some time since the post was made but did you find any implementation of this in the end?

Comment: @aaronward no, unfortunately, there isn't still any implementation for that.

Comment: Only thing i could find was [this](https://github.com/MinhDg00/theta) .. it doesn't work very well but it could be something to take inspiration from if you want to make your own implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you still need it but I found theta forecasting in these two packages:

- [sktime](https://sktime.org/modules/auto_generated/sktime.forecasting.theta.ThetaForecaster.html#sktime.forecasting.theta.ThetaForecaster)
- [darts](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.theta.html)

Comment: It's now also in statsmodels

Comment: You will need `statsmodels >= 12.0.0`. [Example implementation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/theta-model.html) and [Documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.forecasting.theta.ThetaModel.html).